# When to use a Bitmap vs Byte[] in Android development?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm dealing with images captured within my app and I'm not sure how to handle them. I've seen some resources use a Bitmap and then ultimately return a Byte[] from that Bitmap, but some just use the Bitmap. Is there a use case for one over the other? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when i want to send and receive image internet i use byte array , but the only time i use bitmap is getting image from camera and convert it to other format , bitmap file are kind of big and i don't want to consume that much internet connection or space to save them

Comment: That makes sense, so what I'm trying to do is take a screenshot of a screen once a user navigates away from it and then add it to a "recent screen" page to allow the user to multitask between that different screens. I'm not sending any data over the internet, so would the Bitmap be okay? Or is space scarce enough to go ahead and use the Byte[]?

Comment: yes i think this is good but since you are working with text convert it to png , because it would require less internal space and in other hand less memory will be required (if i'm not right and you have picture of nature or something use jpeg)